# Finding out the original author of a shared post (the "via X" while reading the newsfeed)

Tags: facebook, stream, facebook-fql

While fetching the stream FQL table you can see entries as link post (type_id is set to 80), the attachment attribute says it's a video (in this specific case) but I see no way to find the original post_id used for the "via" while reading the news feed through on a desktop browser

[image: screenshot]

The JSON result of the stream entry :

```
{
    "action_links" = "<null>";
    "actor_id" = 100001815824671;
    "app_data" =     (
    );
    "app_id" = 2309869772;
    attachment =     {
        caption = "";
        description = "Parce qu'il appris en 2007 qu'une photo pouvait lui jouer des tours, Nicolas Sarkozy a verrouill\U00e9 l'espace des photographes. Mais dans les interstices qui le...";
        "fb_object_type" = "";
        href = "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IF-9UqwjcXs&feature=share";
        icon = "https://s-static.ak.facebook.com/rsrc.php/v1/yj/r/v2OnaTyTQZE.gif";
        media =         (
                        {
                alt = "Nicolas Sarkozy, des photographes \U00abSous Contr\U00f4le\U00bb, Olivier Laban-Mattei, Parole de Photographes";
                href = "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IF-9UqwjcXs&feature=share";
                src = "https://s-external.ak.fbcdn.net/safe_image.php?d=AQDtTtxmIkrFXsoO&w=130&h=130&url=http%3A%2F%2Fi2.ytimg.com%2Fvi%2FIF-9UqwjcXs%2Fhqdefault.jpg";
                type = video;
                video =                 {
                    "display_url" = "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IF-9UqwjcXs";
                    "source_type" = html;
                    "source_url" = "http://www.youtube.com/v/IF-9UqwjcXs?version=3&autohide=1&autoplay=1";
                };
            }
        );
        name = "Nicolas Sarkozy, des photographes \U00abSous Contr\U00f4le\U00bb, Olivier Laban-Mattei, Parole de Photographes";
        properties =         (
        );
    };
    attribution = "<null>";
    comments =     {
        "can_post" = 1;
        "can_remove" = 0;
        "comment_list" =         (
        );
        count = 0;
    };
    "created_time" = 1335282879;
    description = "Rencontre Photographique shared a link.";
    "filter_key" = nf;
    likes =     {
        "can_like" = 1;
        count = 0;
        friends =         (
        );
        href = "http://www.facebook.com/browse/likes/?id=275584819202502";
        sample =         (
        );
        "user_likes" = 0;
    };
    message = "";
    permalink = "http://www.facebook.com/permalink.php?story_fbid=275584819202502&id=100001815824671";
    "post_id" = "100001815824671_275584819202502";
    privacy =     {
        value = "";
    };
    "source_id" = 100001815824671;
    "target_id" = "<null>";
    type = 80;
    "updated_time" = 1335282879;
}
```

The original post (I found it manually following the original post and looking at its id, as nothing in the stream result allows me to find this) coming from http://graph.facebook.com/282715205093918_325763324158342:

```
{
  "id": "282715205093918_325763324158342", 
  "from": {
    "name": "B+M Paris", 
    "category": "Health/beauty", 
    "id": "282715205093918"
  }, 
  "message": "Une fiche qui permet de comprendre comment notre peau évolue avec le temps", 
  "picture": "https://s-external.ak.fbcdn.net/safe_image.php?d=AQCssWcIVgdWpXMd&w=90&h=90&url=http\u00253A\u00252F\u00252Fsante.lefigaro.fr\u00252Fsites\u00252Fdefault\u00252Ffiles\u00252Fmedia\u00252Ffield_visuel\u00252Fmebeau006_0.jpg", 
  "link": "http://sante.lefigaro.fr/mieux-etre/sante-beaute/vieillissement-cutane/comment-vieillit-peau", 
  "name": "Vieillissement cutané : Comment vieillit la peau ?", 
  "caption": "sante.lefigaro.fr", 
  "description": "Le premier processus de vieillissement intrinsèque, naturel, dont le rythme est génétiquement déterminé. Progressivement, les cellules de l’organisme entrent en sénescence. Les différents mécanismes de maintenance de la peau s’en trouvent altérés :", 
  "icon": "https://s-static.ak.facebook.com/rsrc.php/v1/yD/r/aS8ecmYRys0.gif", 
  "actions": [
    {
      "name": "Comment", 
      "link": "https://www.facebook.com/282715205093918/posts/325763324158342"
    }, 
    {
      "name": "Like", 
      "link": "https://www.facebook.com/282715205093918/posts/325763324158342"
    }
  ], 
  "type": "link", 
  "created_time": "2012-04-19T14:56:59+0000", 
  "updated_time": "2012-04-19T14:56:59+0000", 
  "shares": {
    "count": 1
  }, 
  "likes": {
    "data": [
      {
        "name": "B+M Paris", 
        "category": "Health/beauty", 
        "id": "282715205093918"
      }
    ], 
    "count": 3
  }, 
  "comments": {
    "count": 0
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to retrieve data on the user who shared a post - it isn't available via the public FQL or Graph API. See [this](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/243877272344703) bug report /feature request and Facebook's response on adding it as a feature: it's on the 'wish list'.

Comment: Ok I see, sad. I accept this as an answer, hopefully Facebook will implement this one day.